# Having stylesheet <link> in <body>?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Is it a bad idea to link CSS files inside the `body`?

I've read that the browser is forced to start CSS rendering over again if it finds another CSS file outside of `head`, just because it might need to apply styles to elements it's already rendered. Also I don't think the HTML will validate properly (I need to confirm this).

Are there any other reasons?

Comment: Is there any reason why you *would* want to do this?

Comment: Who said anything about *wanting* to do this? :) I'm working on a .net project where they link specific style sheets at the top of user controls. Thats what brought on the question. I'm not a fan of this at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I've seen people use to justify doing this is when they're using certain templating engines, and they can't arbitrarily change the stylesheets linked in the head when loading new content or a particular view (in the case of MVC frameworks).

Either way, this should be avoided at all costs as it's sloppy, and improper. Instead, always develop your projects in such a way that you can get an arbitrary stylesheet into the head at any time. I generally do this by cycling through a stylesheet array in the head. That way, if I need to add a new stylesheet, I simply add its pathname to the array to be printed in the head.

```
<?php

  $styles   = array();
  $styles[] = "css/main.css";
  $styles[] = "css/text.css";

?>

<head>
  <?php foreach ($styles as $style) { ?>
    <link href="<?php print $style; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <?php } ?>
</head>
```

Comment: Does not answer the question. The question doesn't mention PHP at all.

Answer (score 5):

The questions have been answered (is it bad, why...) but the correct way to achive that if you can't add your links (or scripts) in the header, is to dynamically insert them with javascript. It's also sometime a good idea for improving the speed of your code. For the links you can use this function:

```js
function loadCss(url) {
    var link = document.createElement("link");
    link.type = "text/css";
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
}
```

You should use a JavaScript file loader like require.js for the scripts.

Edit bonus: **A way to improve your page loading speed**

In your HTML <head> you have a first small <style> element with for example the body background CSS definitions, some generics ones, the ones for your menu and maybe title (and maybe something for a waiting gif). You have a second one, a link to your non JavaScript related CSS.

You have then to flush the buffer to send the beginning of your HTML until the <body>.

You can then flush another time for the menu and the title.

Finally, you finish flushing the leftover HTML with in the end your JS for dynamically insert your CSS JS related links (maybe another for hiding the waiting gif) and your JS scripts links.

This is especially useful for heavy pages or if you have a lot of server processing time.

Comment: This is the best answer here. The only one, that actually provides a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The HTML standard (at least HTML 4 that I looked at) [mandates](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.3) that the `<link>` tag must be in the `<head>`. There is no telling what browsers will do with a `<link>` in the `<body>`. If I were building a browser I'd probably ignore it.

And why on earth would you even want this?

Comment: I've got a feeling some will load it and others won't

Answer (score 3):

Having a `link` element with the `stylesheet` link type in the `body` is **allowed in**

- the current version of WHATWG’s HTML (2016-07-28), see [`link`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-link-element): [allowed in the body](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#allowed-in-the-body)/[body-ok](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#body-ok)
- the current draft of W3C’s HTML 5.2 (2016-07-04), see [`link`](https://w3c.github.io/html/document-metadata.html#the-link-element): [allowed in the body](https://w3c.github.io/html/document-metadata.html#allowed-in-the-body)/[body-ok](https://w3c.github.io/html/links.html#body-ok)

and **not allowed in**

- W3C’s HTML5 (Recommendation from 2014), see [`link`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-link-element)
- the current Candidate Recommendation of W3C’s HTML 5.1 (2016-06-21), see [`link`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-html51-20160621/document-metadata.html#the-link-element)

Comment: Mozilla's [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) also say it's OK to have CSS links in the body (see the Notes section)

Answer (score 0):

You either link to external stylesheet or write it directly, both in head, it won't work if you'll try differently.

Answer (score 0):

I use JQuery UI, but only in Member's Area zone, where lot of interactivity is happening.
In my static pages, no JQuery UI is used, therefore this link went to body, after `<?PHP include "header.php" ?>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css" />
```

I'll restrain from saying it is OK, but I can confirm that I've not seen anything rendered wrong by any of modern browsers so far.