# how to link js to html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<link rel = "stylesheet"
   type = "text/css"
   href = "stylesheet.css" />
<div id="bg"></div>
<h2>Kiran Murthy JD</h2>
<section>
  <nav>
    <div></div>
    <ul>
      <li data-xcoord="0px" class="active">About</li>
      <li data-xcoord="160px">Portfolio</li>
      <li data-xcoord="320px">Contact</li>
      <!--<li data-xcoord="480px">Store</li>-->
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http:///ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javas.js"></script>
</body>
```

And following is the js file I want to link, Filename is javas.js

```
$("nav ul li").click(function(){
  var xcoord = $(this).data("xcoord");

  $("nav div").stop().animate({marginLeft:xcoord}, 400, "easeInOutExpo");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $("nav ul li").not(this).removeClass("active");

});
```

I also have CSS file which I am able to link successfully. But, java scripts are not linking at all. I'm not sure which js files are not linking i.e., The online js files or javas.js local file.
**I'm using sublime Text 3**

Comment: `jquery.min.js` must be first in order as code in other files is dependent on jQuery .

Comment: @MohammadUsman tried it, No effect

Comment: By the way, where is the `head` section in your document?

Comment: "But, java scripts are not linking at all" — How are you establishing this? Have you used the Developer Tools in the browser? Have you checked the Network tab? Is a request being made for the JS files? Are they getting responses? Do the responses give you 200 OK statuses? What about the Console? Does it show any error messages?

Comment: Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/), a `<link>` can't go inside the `<body>` and the `<title>` is missing.

Comment: @Quentin it actually can in some cases. (Not valid and correct), reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38645502/4108884. P.S: That's not relevant to the topic though.

Comment: @Quentin I'm getting the following error for both js files IO Error: Non-XML Content-Type: text/javascript.
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: please check browser devtools console for errors and report (hit F12 in Chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "stylesheet.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http:///ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="bg"></div>
<h2>Kiran Murthy JD</h2>
<section>
  <nav>
    <div></div>
    <ul>
      <li data-xcoord="0px" class="active">About</li>
      <li data-xcoord="160px">Portfolio</li>
      <li data-xcoord="320px">Contact</li>
      <!--<li data-xcoord="480px">Store</li>-->
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
</body>
```

try this it will work i guess

Comment: can i know what output are you expecting if you link the JS file because it didn't show any error in my console so just asking so that i can help you

Answer (score 0):

```
You should be changed scripts sequence.


 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<link rel = "stylesheet"
   type = "text/css"
   href = "stylesheet.css" />
<div id="bg"></div>
<h2>Kiran Murthy JD</h2>
<section>
  <nav>
    <div></div>
    <ul>
      <li data-xcoord="0px" class="active">About</li>
      <li data-xcoord="160px">Portfolio</li>
      <li data-xcoord="320px">Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http:///ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javas.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```